# Searching an exemple of C# code to display a panoramic 360 picture in WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I'd like to be able to display a panoramic 360 equirectangular image in a WPF Application.
Like this http://norikdavtian.github.io/ThreeJS-360-Panorama/
In this link, Three.js is used but I'd like to do it in C#
How to do it?
Many thx